# What tools are available to monitor single-page app performance while developing?

Tags: javascript, performance

As a full-stack developer with a strong penchant for the backend, I am embarking on the task of developing a single-page app for the browser using Javascript. While I do this, I would like a way to monitor the performance of the application (memory consumption, CPU consumption, event-based render times, network utilization) in a simple and unified way.

I am aware of Firebug for Firefox and that it has a profiler feature. I'm not as familiar with Chrome's tools. What tools are available for monitoring/profiling performance in each browser that I can use while developing to keep an eye on how my code changes are affecting performance? I don't know where to begin other than Firebug in Firefox and I have no idea if that's sufficient.

Comment: [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now), maybe.

Comment: Firebug in firefox and pagespeed in chrome and yslow in IE and GTMetrix for third party evaluation with suggestions, maybe. :)